# Non-linear PDE in 2D periodic domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, periodic-functions

I am developing a pseudo-spectral code for the vorticity transport equation. In order to validate the correct computation of the nonlinear (convective) term in the physical space, I have first solved the 1D Burgers equation and compared the numerical result with an analytical solution for a periodic domain. This worked fine.

Now I aim to do the same thing with the 2D Burgers equation or any other PDE containing a nonlinear term such as $u_j\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$,

$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t}+u_j\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}=\nu\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j^2}$.

However, I am struggling to find an exact solution for the 2D Burgers equation in a periodic domain (maybe it doesn't exist, I don't know..). If it doesn't, which other PDE of this family could I use for this purpose? Or in which other way could I validate my numerical solution?

Comment: What is the equation you are using? Does it include viscosity?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I will update my question with the 2D Burgers equation.

Comment: Any comments on this please?

Comment: Actually the Taylor-Green vortex in 2D has an analytical unsteady solution. The problem is that the convective term cancels because of the flow symmetry, and this result in a gradual dissipation of the initial state.